# Proof of this sum involving binomials

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

Why this the following true?

\[ \sum_{k=0}^{M}((n-k)-k)\binom{n}{k} = (M+1)\binom{n}{M+1} \]

[Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum+k+%3D+0+to+M+of+choose%28n%2Ck%29*%28n-2k%29) tells me it is, but I'm having trouble reasoning through it. Is there an intuitive reason why we should expect this to be true (eg, like there's an intuitive reason that $\sum_{k=0}^n \binom{n}{k} = 2^n$), or should I just try expanding the binomials to factorials and see what reduces?

*This came up in relation to a [Quanta Magazine puzzle](https://www.quantamagazine.org/20150903-the-road-less-traveled/) from [r/math](https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/3jmm80/can_you_solve_this_puzzle_the_road_less_traveled/).*

Answer (score 6):

Here’s a purely algebraic demonstration; it uses the standard identities $\binom{n}k=\binom{n}{n-k}$ and $k\binom{n}k=n\binom{n-1}{k-1}$. I’ll think more about the possibility of a combinatorial argument.

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^M\big((n-k)-k\big)\binom{n}k&=\sum_{k=0}^M(n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}-\sum_{k=0}^Mk\binom{n}k\\
&=\sum_{k=n-M}^nk\binom{n}k-\sum_{k=0}^Mk\binom{n}k\\
&=n\left(\sum_{k=n-M}^n\binom{n-1}{k-1}-\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{n-1}{k-1}\right)\\
&=n\left(\sum_{k=n-M-1}^{n-1}\binom{n-1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\binom{n-1}k\right)\\
&=n\left(\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{n-1}k-\sum_{k=0}^{M-1}\binom{n-1}k\right)\\
&=n\binom{n-1}M\\
&=(M+1)\binom{n}{M+1}
\end{align*}$$

**Added:** It’s simpler if you rewrite it as

$$\sum_{k=0}^M(n-k)\binom{n}k=\sum_{k=0}^{M+1}k\binom{n}k\;.\tag{1}$$

You then have

$$\begin{align*}
\sum_{k=0}^{M+1}k\binom{n}k&=n\sum_{k=0}^{M+1}\binom{n-1}{k-1}\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{n-1}k\\
&=n\sum_{k=0}^M\binom{n-1}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^M(n-k)\binom{n}{n-k}\\
&=\sum_{k=0}^M(n-k)\binom{n}k\;.
\end{align*}$$

And in this form a combinatorial argument suggests itself. Suppose that you have a group of $n$ players. You want to select a team of up to $M+1$ of them, including a designated captain. There are $(n-k)\binom{n}k$ ways to select $k$ non-captains and then to select a captain from the remaining $n-k$ players, so the lefthand side of $(1)$ counts the number of ways to form such teams. Alternatively, we can select the entire team of $k$ players in $\binom{n}k$ ways and then pick a captain from the selected players in $k$ ways, for a total of $k\binom{n}k$ teams with $k$ players. Thus, the righthand side of $(1)$ also counts the total number of teams that we can form.